# Remote into Windows 10 from Android - the risks

Tags: windows, android, virus, remote-access

I wish to remote to my computer, running Windows 10, from my tablet, running Android 4.4. The how to I could search online and sooner or later I would be done. It is the risks that I fear, because my tablet's antivirus is a free AVG, clearly isn't the best protection. My laptop has an ESET 9 on it though, but I bet remote access would give full rights from my tablet. So the question again, what are the risks of remoting into my computer from my tablet, given the above info? Or is it possible to disconnect my tablet from the net and use the router only for LAN thus managing the risks?

**EDIT:**

I do not bank on the tablet, only on the PC. The thing I worry about is this: while using this remote **only from home**, I get a virus to my tablet which can get access to my PC via this remote.

The whole purpose of this remote is that I wish to develop software from lying in my bed but my Android tablet is incapable of running an IDE so I use my pc remotely.

Comment: If you are on the local network than nothing to worry, but if you want to open ports on your router and forward it to Windows - it kinda questionable. Windows doesn't have  protection against brute-force attacks, so it could be exploited in case of weak passwords. What I usually do - I set SSH server on windows (since it support public key cryptography) and connecting to RDP via reversed SSH ports

Comment: Thanks for the update. 
That's what I thought, to cut meself from the internet while remoting. Plan to use it only from home. 
By the way, I have a router here which is used by others as well. How do I do that both my pc and tablet accesses the local network, but none of them the internet?

Comment: Just disconnect cable from WAN port

Comment: I might not understand correctly. The router has to be able to provide others using it with internet, and I have to be able to connect to the router on both devices to use remote, but none of my devices can access the internet.

Comment: Or, I do have a separate router at home, which I don't have to connect to the internet. Shall I use that? So I have that running, I set up a local network and none of my devices access the net, only each other via the separate router?

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried that you could lose your phone or tablet and someone who found it could access your PC?  That is always possible, but do you do banking on your tablet? I guess it all comes back to passwords. Use something strong not just a simple swipe pattern.

You mention the AVG on the tablet? Are you concerned about malicious software "jumping" from tablet to PC? or vice-versa?

You need to balance your need for security with the benefit of the remote access.

I use this ALOT - to manage my Plex Media Server mainly - 
On Android I use RD Client - it is the mobile version of Microsoft's long standing Remote Desktop (which I also use all the time to control my pcs at home) - I use this on the LAN only and works brilliantly, I am very impressed with it.
When I am remote - I use Chrome Remote Desktop - again works brilliantly, but it does mean I have to have a permanently signed in Chrome extension - and as  much as I trust Google with all my info... that sometimes makes me wonder how much access they have.

So perhaps a risk there?

Chrome:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Microsoft:(LAN)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473010(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update. My question might not be clear, I edit it to clarify.